# compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

A space $(X, \tau)$ is said to strongly $T_B$ if each countably compact subset is closed.

> **Is there an example to show that a space is  compact Hausdorff, but it has countably compact non-closed subset**? ( I mean  compact Hausdorff space in which  is not strongly $T_B$.)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Look at the one point compactification of a discrete uncountable set.

Comment: $X$ is  discrete, so it is locally compact and Hausdorff, then $X^*$ is Hausdorff. $X^*$ is compact, then countably compact. But I do not understand " why dose it have a non closed subset?"

Comment: Look at $X \subset X^{\ast}$